Synchrinization of multiple rtsp camera streams using Valkka(Python media streaming lib)
First of all, it is my first question and apologize for any kind of misunderstanding and errors.
I'm not quiet good at multiprocessing/multihreading, but I'm trying my best.
Currently, I'm  working on streaming/consuming frames from multiple rtsp cameras.
With other approaches like FFMPEG, Opencv etc. necessary performance cannot be reached for now, so,
I found an amazing library for real-time data streaming, called Valkka. I managed 20 FPS in the worst case with this tool. Consuming frames should be saved to storage and also frames' paths need to be written to Redis, in the following format:
{
   camera1: /path/to/camera1/frames.jpg,
   camera2: /path/to/camera2/frames.jpg,
   ....
   ....
   cameraN: /path/to/cameraN/frames.jpg,
}

Here is a problem popping up, in order to save frames' paths to Redis cameras should be synchronized.
Here is a code I tried to solve the problem using this suggestion from the author of the Valkka lib :
import time
from valkka.multiprocess import safe_select
from basic.skeleton.multiprocess.rgb import RGB24Process
from basic.skeleton.singleton import event_fd_group_1


class MyProcess(RGB24Process):

    def preRun__(self):
        super().preRun__()
        from redis import Redis
        self.redis_instance = Redis(host="localhost", port=6379, db=1)

    def readPipes__(self, timeout):
        rlis = [self.back_pipe]
        print("RLIS:    ", rlis)
        # self.back_pipe is the intercom pipe with the main python process
        # listen to all rgb frame sources
        print("CLIENT_BY_FD:    ", self.client_by_fd.values())

        frame_fds = list(self.client_by_fd.keys())
        rlis += frame_fds

        rs, ws, es = safe_select(rlis, [], [], timeout=timeout)
        print("RS:          ", rs)
        print("FRAME_FDS:   ", frame_fds)

        for fd in rs:
            print("FD:      ", fd)
            if fd == self.back_pipe:
                self.handleBackPipe__(self.back_pipe)
            # There is no same item in frame_fds and rs arrays
            if fd in frame_fds:
                client = self.client_by_fd[fd]
                index, meta = client.pullFrame()
                if (index == None):
                    print("RGB24Process: handleFrame__ : weird.. rgb client got none")
                else:
                    print("Not coming to here")
                    data = client.shmem_list[index][0:meta.size]
                    data = data.reshape((meta.height, meta.width, 3))
                    self.handleFrame__(data, meta)

    def handleFrame__(self, frame, meta):
        self.logger.debug("handleFrame__ : rgb client got frame % from slot %s", frame.shape, meta.slot)
        """metadata has the following members:
        size 
        width
        height
        slot
        mstimestamp
        """
        import cv2
        import json
        img = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        image = f"/home/kamol/projects/valkka_sample/frames/{cam_id}/{meta.mstimestamp}.jpg"
        cv2.imwrite(image, img)

        # This code block somehow skipping several frames, which was saved to storage already but had not been push
        self.frames_collection[cam_id] = image
        if len(self.frames_collection) == 10:
            self.redis_client.rpush("camerasynchronizerviavalkka", json.dumps(self.frames_collection))
            self.frames_collection.clear()


class LiveStream:

    def __init__(self, shmem_buffers, shmem_name, address, slot, width, height):
        from valkka.core import AVThread, RGBShmemFrameFilter, SwScaleFrameFilter, LiveConnectionContext, \
            LiveConnectionType_rtsp
        self.shmem_buffers = shmem_buffers
        self.shmem_name = shmem_name
        self.address = f"rtsp://user:password@{address}:554"
        self.slot = slot
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

        _, self.event = event_fd_group_1.reserve()

        self.shmem_filter = RGBShmemFrameFilter(self.shmem_name, self.shmem_buffers, self.width, self.height)
        self.shmem_filter.useFd(self.event)

        # SWS Filter
        self.sws_filter = SwScaleFrameFilter(f"sws_{self.shmem_name}", width, height, self.shmem_filter)
        # self.interval_filter = TimeIntervalFrameFilter("interval_filter", 0, self.sws_filter)

        # decoding part
        self.avthread = AVThread("avthread", self.sws_filter)
        # self.av_in_filter = self.avthread.getBlockingFrameFilter()
        self.av_in_filter = self.avthread.getFrameFilter()

        # define connection to camera
        self.ctx = LiveConnectionContext(LiveConnectionType_rtsp, self.address, self.slot, self.av_in_filter)

        self.avthread.startCall()
        self.avthread.decodingOnCall()

    def close(self):
        self.avthread.decodingOffCall()
        self.avthread.stopCall()
        self.event.release()


p = MyProcess()
p.start()

from valkka.core import LiveThread
from config import get_configs

conf = get_configs()
cameras = conf.get("cameras", [0])
width = conf.get("image_width", 1920)
height = conf.get("image_height", 1080)
shmem_buffers = conf.get("shared_memory_buffers", 10)
mstimeout = conf.get("mstimeout", 10)

shmem_names = []
livestreams = {}
livethread = LiveThread("Livethread")
for i, cam in enumerate(cameras, start=1):
    livestreams[i] = LiveStream(
        shmem_buffers=shmem_buffers,
        shmem_name=f"{cam}",
        address=cam,
        slot=i,
        width=width,
        height=height
    )
    print("LIVETHREAD SHMEM: ", livestreams[i].shmem_name)

livethread.startCall()

for livestream in livestreams.values():
    livethread.registerStreamCall(livestream.ctx)
    livethread.playStreamCall(livestream.ctx)
    shmem_names.append(livestream.shmem_name)
    print("LIVESTREAM SHMEM:    ", livestream.shmem_name)
    fd = p.activateRGB24Client(
        name=livestream.shmem_name,
        n_ringbuffer=100,
        width=1920,
        height=1080,
        ipc_index=event_fd_group_1.asIndex(livestream.event)
    )

time.sleep(20)
p.stop()

Thanks from beforehand for any kind of suggestions.
EDIT
In handleFrame__ I'm trying to do 2 things:

save frames to memory
push saved frames to Redis

Problems

FPS dropping to 10 when FullHD resolution frames encoding, but it is stably giving 20 fps when the resolution is decreased to HD or lower.
saved and pushed to redis frames are making difference. Not all frames are being pushed by the order of saving to memory. Some frames are being skipped when pushed to redis.
For example:

frames in the dirs:
cam1                cam2               cam3
    --img1.jpg          --img1.jpg         --img1.jpg
    --img2.jpg          --img2.jpg         --img2.jpg
    ...                 ...                ...
    --imgN.jpg          --imgN.jpg         --imgN.jpg


objects in redis array:
1 -> {
         cam1: "path/to/cam1/img1.jpg",
         cam3: "path/to/cam3/img3.jpg",
         cam2: "path/to/cam2/img5.jpg", 
     }
2 -> {
         cam3: "path/to/cam1/img2.jpg",
         cam1: "path/to/cam1/img8.jpg",
         cam2: "path/to/cam1/img9.jpg",
     }


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

@СергейКох Thanks for your reaction sir. I updated the question.
